# How to print items from list that haven't been printed?

Tags: python

My question is, how to print only items that haven't been printed? 
(it's just part of the code). 
I have an array of 15 items that has to be shuffled, then print only the quantity that `e/2` is. I've tried by making a second list with the indexes of the items from the array and then printing only the indexes and items that are present on my list. If an index is not on my list then it will not be printed. After every print the index of the item is removed from my made up list so it won't be printed for the second time.

```
def tryitem(self,c,list1):
    if c not in lista:
        c = random.randint(0, 14)
        self.tryitem(c,list1)
    else:
        pass


 ...some code...


 list1 = list(range(15))
 for i in range(int(e/2)):
             c = random.randint(0, 14)
             print(c)
             self.tryitem(c,list1)
             but= ttk.Button(root, text=str(item.myItem[c][0])+" x"+str(item.myItem[c][1]))
             but.place(anchor=W,x=20,y=wysokosc,width=170,height=25)
             wysokosc+=25
             list1.remove(item.myItem[c][2])
```

indexes of the items are at `myItem[c][2]` column
First of all this method doesn't work as it should, because it is printing some items two to three times, and after some prints I get the error

> ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: use dictionary instead of list.

Comment: what is `e`? `exp(1)`?

Comment: no, it's just a number between 1 and 30

Answer (score 0):

I'll try answering your first question, assuming you have a list and you want to print it's items in some kind of iteration, and you want to keep track on what items has been printed already in order to not print them again.

The easiest way is to use a dictionary.
Every time you print an item, add his index to the dictionary.
Every time you want to print an item, check if his index is in the dictionary, and print only if it does not.

```
import random

e = random.randint(1, 30)
lst = [random.randint(1, 1000) for _ in range(100)]
printed = {}  # To save if we perinted this index already

def print_next_values():
    for x in range(int(e/2)):  # print (e/2) items
        index = random.randint(0, len(lst) - 1)
        # Try to fetch new indexes until we get a new index we havn't printed yet
        while index in printed:
            index = random.randint(0, len(lst) - 1)

        print(lst[index])  # Printing the item
        printed[index] = True  # Adding the item index to the dictionary

while len(printed.keys()) < len(lst):
    print_next_values()
```

Here you can see a list of 1000 items, that will be printed in parts (e/2 every iteration, until there is no more items).
Before we print an item, we check if he has been printed already. If not, we print it.